# run php script onclick link with javascript

Tags: php, logging, onclick, ip

i have make this script for log last ip client address:

```
$logfile= 'ip.html';
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$logdetails= date("F j, Y, g:i a") . ': ' . '<a href=https://showip.net/?checkip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' target=_blank>'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'</a>';
$fp = fopen($logfile, "r+");
fwrite($fp, $logdetails, strlen($logdetails));
fclose($fp);
```

but i need to run it to onclick html link and log all times not only last, maybe use javascript? please help me

Comment: Ajax is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ajax to make a call to your php.script whenever you click on an element.

```
$('.element_you_click').on('click', function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'path/to/your/script.php',
        success: function(response){
            #whatever you want to do after the script
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you!

**EDIT:**

If you want to send variables to your script on this call just add these lines:

```
data:{"variable1" : value1, "variable2" : value2},
type: "GET", #or POST
```

and then retrieve the data on your script with `$_GET['variable1']` and `$_GET['variable2']`.

Comment: sorry i dont know ajax be patient...
my html file:
<a href="#" onclick="get_client_ip()">CMON</a>
<script>
$('.href').on('click', function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'test.php',
    });
});
</script>
test.php is my first example, dont work.. .why?

Comment: @medo use a div or button element instead of `a href` and give this element a distinctive id: `<div id='element_to_click'>CMON</div>` and then on javascript do this: `$('#element_to_click').on('click',function(){jQuery.ajax({url: 'route/to/your/test.php'})});`. The url value should be the path to your file. Your sentence would be correct if that script is on the same folder.

Comment: @medo if it still doesn't work be sure to check your `error.log` file for PHP errors and inspect page for possible javascript errors.